# How to delete unwanted Sender (me) addresses in OS X Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

I have a few email addresses in the dropdown list of Senders (i.e., my own email addresses that I send mail From) which are obsolete. One of them includes the string "4Q2delist@mac.com" which I never had as part of any email address.

Anyway, I want to delete these outdated email addresses from this list. NOTE: the list I am referring to is not the "recent recipients" list - it's the list of my own email addresses.

Does anyone know how to do this, or know what "4Q2delist" means, or where this file (presumably a property list) is located?

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4, Mail 8.2. Removing aliases in iCloud didn't do anything.

Comment: OS X and mail app versions please!

Comment: OS X Yosemite 10.10.4, Mail 8.2 
I'm referring to the dropdown list that comes from the "From:" line when you start a new email. It has 10 different items in it. How can I edit this thing - I only have 2 actual dot-mac (iCloud) addresses? Removing aliases in iCloud didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

In Mail.app go to Preferences → Accounts → Alias

[image]

Then select Edit Aliases in the drop down list:

[image]

It should take you to icloud.com mail settings where you can edit them all:

[image]

Comment: Where would Alias be? I can't find it on the route you suggest. Is it iCloud specific maybe?

Comment: Check the image I edited in.

Comment: Great! As I don't use iCloud for mail, I haven't seen it before.

Comment: Those aliases that have the string "4q2delist" added before .mac, .me, and .iCloud are impossible to get rid of. I searched for them in Terminal, found a few emails that had them, nuked those, then found a plist that had them, removed them from that, then locked the plist, and Mail STILL has those in there. Those 3 aliases do NOT appear in the "Edit Aliases" list in iCloud Mail, so that is not a way to delete them.
NOTE: all 3 of these rogue aliases are on my secondary Apple email account (extra $10 per year I think).

Comment: I've edited the main answer with more details, have you tried that?